# Does reading a binary file linewise in python cause problems for unicode data?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, newline, filehandle

I'm reading a large (10Gb) bzipped file in python3, which is utf-8-encoded JSON. I only want a few of the lines though, that start with a certain set of bytes, so to save having to decode all the lines into unicode, I'm reading the file in 'rb' mode, like this:

```
with bz2.open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith(b'Hello'):
            #decode line here, then do stuff
```

But I suddenly thought, what if one of the unicode characters contains the same byte as a newline character? By doing `for line in file` will I risk getting truncated lines? Or does the linewise iterator over a binary file still work by magic?

Comment: Btw, besides my answer: the `codecs.iterdecode` function might be relevant to your use case, as you seem concerned about processing speed. I never benchmarked it, but I guess it might save some overhead compared to `line.decode('utf8')`. Wrap your existing code in a generator function and pass it as the first argument to `iterdecode()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line-wise iteration will work for UTF-8 encoded data.
Not by magic, but by design:
UTF-8 was created to be backwards-compatible to ASCII.

ASCII only uses the byte values 0 through 127, leaving the upper half of possible values for extensions of any kind.
UTF-8 takes advantage of this, in that any Unicode codepoint outside ASCII is encoded using bytes in the range 128..255.

For example, the letter "Ċ" (capital letter C with dot above) has the Unicode codepoint value `U+010A`.
In UTF-8, this is encoded with the byte sequence `C4 8A`, thus without using the byte `0A`, which is the ASCII newline.

In contrast, UTF-16 encodes the same character as `0A 01` or `01 0A` (depending on the Endianness).
So I guess UTF-16 is not safe to do line-wise iteration over.
It's not that common as file encoding though.